# Looking for Research on Loss Aversion

Tags: user-research, psychology, marketing

We're dealing with an ongoing research process and finding some noticeable pain points, specifically related to *loss aversion* (this is for a risk investments app).

After lots of brainstorming, we're still having a tough time in terms of reducing friction (our failure is validated by research), so I'd like to know if there is any **tool, recommendation, research or paper** dealing with *loss aversion* in general, preferably applied to the *investments and risk of monetary loss* subject.

Just to be clear: **I'm well aware of principles of scarcity and loss aversion**, and we have a behavioral psychologist on our team, so identifying the problem or why is it happening is NOT the issue. **I'm looking for ideas and strategies to overcome this pain point**, at least something we can test with users

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prospect_theory

Try this for background reading Devin.

Comment: Thanks @PhillipW, as. Aa a matter of fact I had it in my bookmarks because someone posted this link sometimes ago (probably you!). Very helpful indeed

Comment: If you fancy a bit of background reading there are some nice examples from Tversky and Kahneman in chapters 16 and 17 of this book - the rest of book might also be interesting if you're interested in financial risk.  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Against-Gods-Remarkable-Story-Risk/dp/0471295639

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a magic bullet; you'd have to experiment (fun!). Finding the variables to manipulate would be critical. With just a cursory knowledge of your problem space, I'd try altering the [framing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_effect_(psychology)) of the information your users are given. That framing adjustment may make them more or less aversive to loss (by virtue of how much they view it as a loss).